# LINQ SELECT with Max and Where in SUBQUERY

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to code the following `SQL` statement into `LINQ`, but struggling.  Here is the `SQL` statement:

```
SELECT C.ITM_CD, C.BUY_QTY, C.COST
  FROM CST C
 WHERE C.eff_dt IN (SELECT MAX (D.eff_dt)
                      FROM CST D
                     WHERE D.itm_cd = C.itm_cd
                       AND D.eff_dt <= '22-APR-2014')
 ORDER BY C.itm_cd
```

And here is my `LINQ` attempt that brings nothing back, even though EVERY `eff_dt` has a date less than today's date and keep in mind, in my 'real' program this date will be changing.

```
var results = from c in Csts
              let MaxEffDate = (from d in Csts
                                where d.EffDt <= DateTime.Parse("04/22/2014").Date
                                   && d.ItmCd == c.ItmCd
                                select d.EffDt).Max()
              where c.EffDt.Equals(MaxEffDate)
              select new
              {
                  c.ItmCd,
                  c.BuyQty,
                  c.Content
              };
```

Lambda code would be great!  So for each `itm_cd` row in the `CST` table, I want all the rows to come back that have the Max effective date for that `itm_cd` as long as the `eff_dt <= a certain date`. I hard-coded today's date so that I know every row should be coming back, but I get nothing.

I've seen a lot of sub-selects on this site but they always use the `MAX` function without a `WHERE` clause of `<=` for that `MAX` column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't really test this at the moment, but something like this should get you close:

```
var results = Csts.Where(d => 
                         d.EffDt == Csts.Where(x => 
                                               x.ItmCd == d.ItmCd && 
                                               x.EffDt <= DateTime.Now)
                                        .Max(x => x.EffDt))
                  .OrderBy(d => d.ItmCd)
                  .Select(d => new { d.ItmCd, d.BuyQty, d.Content });
```

Comment: Wow!  Worked like a charm.  I changed dates and the results were just great!  Now I need to go digest this and see what I didn't understand.  Thanks!!