# GroupBy in subquery with MAX() in C#

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, subquery, ef-core-5.0

I Have this code. It works fine but when I have two same maximal values it appear 2 times. So I need to use OrderBy. But I dont know how. Thanks for any help.

```cs
IQueryable<PerformanceRealization> pr = _context.PerformanceRealization
    .Where(u => u.Deadline == _context.PerformanceRealization
        .Where(x => x.GroupRealizationId == u.GroupRealizationId)
        .Max(x => x.Deadline)
    )
    .Select(u => u);
```

Here is the SQL code with GROUP BY

```sql
SELECT PR.GroupRealizationId
FROM Stores.PerformanceRealization PR
LEFT JOIN Stores.GroupRealization ON Stores.GroupRealization.Id = PR.GroupRealizationId
WHERE PR.Deadline = (SELECT MAX(Deadline) 
                     FROM Stores.PerformanceRealization PR2 
                     WHERE PR.GroupRealizationId = PR2.GroupRealizationId)
GROUP BY PR.GroupRealizationId
```

Comment: Specify which ORM do you use and which version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subquery with MAX() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74482161/subquery-with-max-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Use my answer instead of yours.

Comment: I use Entity Framework 5.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first object from the group

```cs
IQueryable<PerformanceRealization> pr2 = pr
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupRealizationId)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

If you need a specific object from the group, then you can order by another column

```cs
IQueryable<PerformanceRealization> pr2 = pr
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupRealizationId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SomeColumn).First());
```

for `SomeColumn` having the smallest value. For the greatest value, use `OderByDescending` instead.

Of course, you can integrate this approach into the first query:

```cs
IQueryable<PerformanceRealization> pr = _context.PerformanceRealization
    .Where(u => u.Deadline == _context.PerformanceRealization
        .Where(x => x.GroupRealizationId == u.GroupRealizationId)
        .Max(x => x.Deadline)
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupRealizationId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SomeColumn).First());
```

Note, you don't need to have a `Select` at the end like `.Select(u => u)`. Since it has no effect, you can just drop it.

---

If your EF Core version cannot handle it (as revealed in a comment), then transition to LINQ-to-Objects with `AsEnumerable()`, but do the filtering in EF Core to  minimize the number of records sent to the front-end:

```cs
IQueryable<PerformanceRealization> pr = _context.PerformanceRealization
    .Where(u => u.Deadline == _context.PerformanceRealization
        .Where(x => x.GroupRealizationId == u.GroupRealizationId)
        .Max(x => x.Deadline)
    )
    .AsEnumerable() // <===== transition from LINQ-to-EF-Core to LINQ-to-Objects
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupRealizationId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SomeColumn).First());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I add ```GroupBy(x => x.GroupRealizationId)``` it starts return ```IQueryable<IGrouping<Guid, PerformanceRealization>>``` but I need ```IQueryable<PerformanceRealization>```.

Comment: Add the `.Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SomeColumn).First());` how I showed you. This will return a `IQueryable<PerformanceRealization>`.

Comment: Now I have problem with EF.. ```unable to translate the given 'group by' pattern``` and ```.first()' could not be translated```  :(

Comment: This query is translatable only by EF Core 6. Next time specify EF Core version.